# Accessing SQL stored procedures

Tags: c#, thread-safety

The following code is from the DataAccess layer that calls the SQL stored procedure and returns the result set back to the calling code.

```
public class CoffeeDataAccess : ICoffeeDataAccess
    {
        private readonly Database coffeeDatabase;

        public CoffeeDataAccess(ICoffeeShopDatabaseFactory factory)
        {
            this.coffeeDatabase = factory.GetCoffeeDatabase();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Coffee>> GetAllAvailableCoffees()
        {
            IEnumerable<Coffee> coffees = await this.ExecuteCommandAsync("spGetAllCoffees");
            return coffees;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Coffee>> GetCofeesOfTheWeek()
        {
            IEnumerable<Coffee> coffees = await this.ExecuteCommandAsync("spGetCoffeesOfTheWeek");
            return coffees;
        }


        private async Task<IEnumerable<Coffee>> ExecuteCommandAsync(string spName)
        {
            IList<Coffee> coffees;

            using (DbCommand command = this.coffeeDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo" + spName))
            {

                Task<IDataReader> dataReaderTask =
                    Task<IDataReader>.Factory.FromAsync(this.coffeeDatabase.BeginExecuteReader, this.coffeeDatabase.EndExecuteReader, command, null);

                using (IDataReader reader = await dataReaderTask)
                {
                    coffees = new List<Coffee>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Coffee c = new Coffee();
                        c.Id = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
                        c.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                        c.ShortDesc = reader["ShortDesc"].ToString();
                        c.LongDesc = reader["LongDesc"].ToString();
                        c.Price = decimal.Parse(reader["Price"].ToString());
                        c.ImageUrl = reader["ImageUrl"].ToString();
                        c.ImageThumbnailUrl = reader["ImageThumbnailUrl"].ToString();
                        c.CategoryId = int.Parse(reader["CategoryId"].ToString());
                        coffees.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            }

            return coffees;
        }

    }
```

The `CoffeeDataAccess` object is newly instantiated every time when a client code asks for it from the IoC container (registered as Trasient in ASP.NET Core - startup class). Is the method name `ExecuteCommandAsync` thread safe or not?

I think it is because each time a new instance of the `CoffeeDataAccess`class is created but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please change the title to make it a summary of the purpose of the code. (Thread safety is not a purpose of the code, it's an attribute you would like to achieve. Stored procedure is not a purpose of the code, it's an implementation detail. You can explain these in the body of the question, but the title should be about the purpose of the code.)

Comment: @janos: The purpose of the code is DataAcess - thats it. Would not that be so generic title? Please help to decide a suitable title - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless factory.GetCoffeeDatabase(); returns a shared factory I cannot see any problems.

On the Reader `reader.GetInt32(0);` is more efficient.  There are direct calls for all the data type.

Assigning property by property is fine.  I think passing in a constructor is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you Paparazzi, factory.GetCoffeeDatabase() method returns a Database object not a factory object which is not shared.

Comment: reader.GetInt32(0); doesnt take the column name. I cant depend upon the order as it can be changed later in the future. May be an extension method can be written on IDataReader to type cast like this:reader.ItemOrDefault<int>("ID"); and reader.ItemOrDefault<string>("Name"); - thanks!

Comment: @YawarMurtaza Well if you could count on an order you could use ordinal.

Comment: reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")); looks less readable than eader.ItemOrDefault<string>("Name");

Comment: @YawarMurtaza I was referring to efficiency.   reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")); is certainly not efficient.

Comment: @Paparazzi `reader.GetInt32(0); is more efficient` `reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")); is certainly not efficient` any references for those two claims? How much slower is one or the other? Enough to be of importance?

Comment: @Alejandro Depends on your definition of importance.

Comment: @Paparazzi "importance"..... How much gain do you actually get? Given that it's called in the context of a DB call, I would expect C# code to be orders of magnitude slower, and having practically little to no effect on runtime unless called thousands of times a second. Shaving a microsecond every minute is rarely worth the loss of legibility or reliability. But most important, I would still like to see any reference to backup your claims, at least in theory.

Comment: @Alejandro Expect what you want.  Your are rude.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested the code, but the code should be thread safe! All ExecCommandAsync methods are called from within asynchronous functions.